# How can I have the icon items in my QlistWidget insert into the widget, or display, from top to bottom and not left to right?

Tags: python, qlistwidget, pyside2

I am using PySide. I have a QlistWidget that I am populating with icon items. The icons display left to right by default and I would like them to display top to bottom, or have a vertical layout, not a horizontal one. How can I achieve this?

from this:[image]

to this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the [`flow`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#flow-prop) property to `QListView::TopToBottom`:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
    w.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
    w.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(128, 128))
    w.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
    w.setFlow(QtWidgets.QListView.TopToBottom)
    for path in ("icon1.png", "icon2.png"):
        it = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        it.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(path))
        w.addItem(it)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: one side note, what if I wanted the label for the icon to display to the right of the icon and not underneath it? For instance, 'kroger' would display to the right of the icon, not underneath it.

Comment: @winteralfs Maybe a delegate will help implement this feature